# Hive query to get top 3 column values using sum of other column value

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 3 columns which is Key_id, gst, claim_amnt.
A single key_id will have multiple gst values and single gst value has multiple claim_amnt. for example i have table like below.

```
 Key_id   gst     claim_amnt
  1245     5         235
  1245     5         100
  1245     4         254   
  1245     4         542
  1245     4         471
  1245     2         745
  1246     1         24
  1246     1         45
  1246     5         52
  1246     5         42
  1246     4         45
```

sum of claim_amnt for respective gst as per key_id

like

```
key_id  gst   (addition of claim_amnt with respect to its gst)
1245    5     335
1245    4     1267
1245    2     745
1246    1     69
1246    5     94
1246    4     45
```

I need top 3 gst fields which respect to claim_amnt along with respective key_id.

Required output:

```
key_id  gst_top1   gst_top2   gst_top3
1245      4          2           5
1246      5          1           4
```

I can get top3 gst values in a single column values but couldn't make it by separating top3 with 3 different fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a couple levels of aggregation:

```
select key_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then gst end) as gst_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then gst end) as gst_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then gst end) as gst_3
from (select key_id, gst, sum(claim_amt) as claim_amt,
             row_number() over (partition by key_id order by sum(claim_amt) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by key_id, gst
     )
group by key_id;
```